# Most efficient way to get visible markers on a map?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, google-maps, data-structures

I've got a map with tens/hundreds of thousands of markers on it, currently stored in array ([docs for Marker Class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Marker)). I need to find markers that are within current map bounds.

The most obvious way is to loop through the entire array and check if map bounds contain marker, but that is not an efficient way to do it.

What data structure and/or algorithm can help to solve the problem?

Comment: can you give a snippet of this array?

Comment: Probably the chunking usually used for 2D physics engines can be applied here too

Comment: @Ivan array contains google maps Marker class instances, I've added a link to docs

Comment: @gsklainski we know the docs, add a real snippet (<> button) that shows your problem and what youve tried to solve it. Then we can simply take that snippet and make it work...

Comment: If you can order the markers based on latitude or longitude. the filter process could be enhanced with pure javascript. Probably a B-tree data structure may solve the problem. But I wonder if this complexity is necessary, what's the current performance for your basic array. And what performance do you need

Answer (score 0):

I would store the Latitude and Longitude values in a database of some sort and then let the database do all of the calculations. Then all you have to do is wait for the ajax response(which would take anywhere from ~10 - 400ms) and then replace the markers with the new ones that are returned in your query. Rendering 50 markers would be significantly faster than having to track the location of hundreds of thousands of markers on the map while also looping through them to see if they should show up or not. This also allows your single-threaded Javascript to focus on the UI instead of complex calculations.